# Easiest way to share on facebook, twitter and via email?

Tags: facebook, email, twitter, sharing

On a news-site, the client wants me to implement a way to share a story (just a link, really) via Email, facebook and twitter.

I could write some code for each sharing-method, but it seems very likely, that some sort of service or library would exist, that shares the current url to different services. Maybe even with some tracking on what is shared - for statistic purposes.

Does such a service or library exist?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check [AddThis.com](http://www.addthis.com/). It supports [many](http://www.addthis.com/bookmark.php) services. I looks like this
[image: preview].

Answer (score 2):

[AddToAny](http://www.addtoany.com/) is a similar service the already suggested to [AddThis](http://www.addthis.com/).  Cannot give you pros/cons between them.

Answer (score 2):

Lots more options out there.

[Sharethis](http://sharethis.com)

[Gigya Wildfire](http://www.gigya.com/public/Content/Widget.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

easiest way would be just to include a URL that then sent the user to facebook. In otherwords, forget the Addthis.come and use these:

facebook:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=[url to share]&t=[title of content]">link or image</a>
```

Twitter:

```
<a href="http://www.twitter.com/share?url=[url to share]>">link or image</a>
```

Good luck